# Installing Ghost.py

Tags: python, installation, python-3.4, ghost.py

I have installed new system and time has come to install Python and modules I have lost..

I had no problems with `BeautifulSoup` but can't make `Ghost.py` into work!

Using `Fedora 21` and `Python-3.4.3`.

I have tried `pip install pyside` and then `pip install ghost` but I guess it worked only for an old `python 2.7`. Also `pip3 install..` respectively.

It would be awesome if any of you could help me install this module :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to literally call the install for `Ghost.py` since the module isn't named `ghost` through [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Ghost.py/0.1.1).

**Python2:**

```
pip install Ghost.py
```

**Python3:**

```
python3.4 -m ensurepip
pip3.4 install Ghost.py
```

Note: You may need to use `sudo` to install pip.

Then you will be able to use Ghost:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
```

**Note:** Do make sure that you have `OpenSSL` installed **before** any installation of Python where you intend to use `Ghost`.

See: [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).

Comment: I'm getting `ImportError: No module named ghost`

Comment: @Fred, see the updated answer for instructions on how to handle for Python3. Make sure you check which versions of python and pip you're using.

Comment: `python3.4 -m ensurepip` 
`Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 6.0.8 requires SSL/TLS`

Comment: I have `openssl` installed.. What can I do?

Comment: In Fedora it's `openssl-devel` already installed. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: What I've seen is that with this error it either works or you need to reinstall Python3.4. Could you provide the version number of `openssl` as well?

Comment: I just install `python-3.4.3` in place of `python3.4`? Or I can do it somewhere else?

My openssl version is `OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015`

Comment: Reinstalling `python-3.4.3` solved the problem! Will keep in mind that for fututre. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent! It must have to do with the existence of `OpenSSL` prior to the Python3.4 install. Glad to help!

Comment: I found that I had to have openssl-devel installed BEFORE I installed Python 3.4.3 using: ./configure ; make ; make install